# How to export PNG for high quality Printing in Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, png

I want to export as PNG for printing. I have designed a document in Adobe Illustrator and I have used Pantone colours, but the results for printing are very poor.

I have to use PNG for printing because my client insists that I use PNG format only.

I will be very thankful to anyone who will give me suggestions.

Comment: PNG can only support RGB color so what is the purpose of using spot colors if your going to circle around to RGB then back to CMYK? I would suggest your client does not know what they want and you need to send the printer a print ready PDF.

Comment: This question is not very clear. By what process and using what colours is the design being printed? What is 'very poor' about the results? Why does the customer think that it will be fixed by using PNG?

Answer (score 1):

> client insists that I use PNG format only

I have a doubt... Who is supposedly the expert?

Do you go to a doctor, and tell him what he needs to do, in what kind of treatment? Inclusive if that does not work?

Some reasons why that is simply wrong:

**1)** If you have it in vectors leave it in vectors. Not in raster format.

**2)** If you have it on pantones, leave it in pantones, do not convert it to RGB which will be converted again into CMYK.

**3)** Send a document that has print information, like dimensions and CMYK Color Profile. A PDF solves this.

---

There is a chance this still does not resolve some colour issues, but that is a separated one. Calibrating the file to the specific output.